# Adobe Animate: Canvas responsive set to width: height isn't ignored

Tags: canvas, adobe-animate

I would like to have my Adobe Animate Canvas only to be horizontally responsive.
But no matter what I change in the settings, the height is being set to 100% viewport height.

My canvas is pretty big in height so I only want the width to be set 100% max of the container.

Am I missing something here?